# Help with cleaning up disk volumes

Tags: disk-utility, monterey

I was using the Disk Utility to create 3 partitions (Linux, Shared, Swap) in order to install a dual boot Linux.  The Linux partition was gigen 100GB, and Shared with 20GB.  Both were created successfully.  Creating Swap failed two times for some reason, resulting in a messy disk structure:

```
% diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         114.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         8.1 GB     disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_KFS ⁨⁩                        8.1 GB     disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨LINUX⁩                   100.1 GB   disk0s5
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨Shared⁩                  20.0 GB    disk0s6

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +8.1 GB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +114.5 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     77.0 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 298.6 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.4 GB    disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk2s5s1
```

#3 and #4 on disk0 are the artifact.  Could anyone please advies how to safely clean the two unneeded?

MacOS 12.5.1

Edit: Disk Utility doesn't appear very reliable.  There are failures often times when creating/editing partitions.  The final time I used it was when it made MacOS boot totally inaccessible resulting me fully removing MacOS from the MacBook Pro.  BTW, Xubuntu 22.04 runs superbly on the bare metal, much more smoothly than Monterey.

Comment: What do you want to do with the 16 GB of free space, add that back to the disk0s2 container?

Comment: Thank you @bmike.  Since the two erroneously created partitions could not be used as intended, I wanted them restored in some ways so that I could re-create the swap partition.  I think I ended up successfully deleting (I don't remember the exact process) them before re-creating the swap.